# "Fast" in "Ich habe den Fehler fast gemacht."

Tags: english-to-german, adverb

I want to say

> I almost made the mistake.

Is it correct to say

> Ich habe den Fehler fast gemacht.

I'm not sure about the adverb "fast" here, since it is modifying the verb "gemacht" (as opposed to an adjective.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Fast* is fine. Because the mistake wasn't really made, you would use subjunctive II:

> Ich hätte den Fehler fast gemacht.

Comment: I'm totally confused on the use of subjunctive II here. Normally it would be used for something that didn't happen. But here, "I almost made the mistake" **was** what happened. Why subjunctive II?

Comment: German has a tendency to stress that something didn't actually occur. Here is a similar case: _Es hätte zerbrechen können._ Many other languages would say the possibility was real after all; but German is different.

Comment: I would like to ask a follow-up question, but perhaps it goes beyond the scope of this thread. I marked your answer as correct and posted the follow-up question [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/subjunctive-ii-in-almost-case) instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

A synonymous alternative to *fast* is using *[beinahe](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/beinahe)* here:

> Ich hätte **beinahe** den Fehler gemacht, einen Kommentar zu schreiben, anstatt zu antworten.

Note that if you use the definitve article here, we do expect a further precision of the nature of the mistake in a following subordinate clause. In case the sentence stands alone it is better to use an indefinite article:

> Ich hätte beinahe/fast **einen** Fehler gemacht.

Comment: Bestimmt da denn das Wort "beinahe" schon nicht, dass etwas nicht passiert ist?
Uns das Wort "fast", dass das in ausgedehntem Maße schon?

Ich habe fast einen Eimer Kartoffeln geschält.
Ich habe den Fehler beinahe gemacht. - Ist das korrekt?

Comment: @Deni: In both cases we can interchange *fast* and *beinahe* - it is more of a personal preference which to use (I prefer *beinahe*).

Comment: Das heißt das Wort "beinahe" ist immer mit dem Konj. II anzuwenden?

Comment: @Deni not really: *Er ist fast/beinahe so groß wie sein Vater - Ich wurde fast/beinahe überfahren*

Comment: Mit dem ersten Beispiel ist es schon klar und einfach, da diese mit einem Adjektive verwandt werden. Aber mit dem zweiten:
Ich wurde fast/beinahe überfahren. - Da wurdest du aber nicht überfahren.
Warum sagt man denn da nicht im K II? (Ich würde fast/beinahe überfahren) Ich kann mir das schon selber antworten: weil das der Zukunftsform ähnlich ist.
Wie würde man dann K II fürs Passive sagen?
Gibt es noch Beispiele wo es nicht passiert ist, aber keine K II dabei?

Comment: @Deni: *Ich wäre beinahe überfahren worden.*